# Jest not stopping after running all tests

Tags: reactjs, continuous-integration, jestjs

I've worked with Jest for a while now, but I haven't seen this problem before. I'm using Jest with react-scripts and when I add CI=true to the environment, it doesn't stop running when it's done.

[image]

I have also tried running it with `--forceExit`, but that doesn't seem to do anything either for this case.

The `CI=true` has been added in the `Run/Debug Configurations` window and with Teamcity through the enviroment variable parameter function.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: can your npm test script not set CI to false?

Comment: Why would I want to do that?

Comment: with CI=true are you getting any advantage of jest?

Comment: It’s the CI parameter I need for teamcity/jenkins/ name another CI evironment